# separating number from date in Pandas columns

Tags: python, string, pandas, split

I have a column in pandas that include 100 rows like the following:

```
timeseries

2000-05-01 10:00:00+00:00   0.9
```

it's only the index and I want to separate datetime with the number, and have two columns like:

```
time                                        number

2000-05-01 10:00:00+00:00                    0.9
```

I tried :

```
df['start'] = mydata.str.split(' ').str.get(0)
df['end'] =   mydata.str.split(' ').str.get(1)
```

but the answer is like:

```
                         timeseries     start  end
2017-05-01 10:00:00+00:00   0.9          0.9    NaN
```

How can I separate the index as date and the number columns?

Comment: `df.timeseries.str.rsplit(' ', 1, True)`?

Comment: How many spaces are there between the time and the number part?

Comment: they are separated by some spaces, I don't know exactly how many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Series containing strings:

```
ser = pd.Series(['2000-05-01 10:00:00+00:00   0.9 ', '2000-05-01 10:00:00+00:00   1.2 ']) # some example data
```

then you can do

```
ser_split = ser.str.split().str
df['time'] = ser_split[0] + ' ' + ser_split[1]
df['number'] = ser_split[-1]
```

which gives

```
                        time number
0  2000-05-01 10:00:00+00:00    0.9
1  2000-05-01 10:00:00+00:00    1.2
```

Comment: my data are float and I tried df.apply(str) before implementing your code, but it didn't work out then!!!

Comment: I am not sure I understand your comment. I have assumed that your `timeseries` is a string. Once you split the columns and create the dataframe `df` the two columns are both strings. Now, you can transform `time` to datetime format using `pd.to_datetime(df.time)` and `number` to a float using `df['number'].astype(float)`

Answer (score 2):

In the example you have posted, there are three spaces between time and number part. In that case,

```
df[['timeseries', 'number']] = df.timeseries.str.extract('(.*)\s{3}(.*)')
```

If you know that there are two or more spaces between time and number,

```
df[['timeseries', 'number']] = df.timeseries.str.extract('(.*)\s\s+(.*)')
```

For a more generic case,

```
df['number'] = df.timeseries.str.split('\s+').str[-1]
df['timeseries'] = df.timeseries.str.split('\s+').str[:-1].apply(' '.join)
```

In all the cases you get,

```
    timeseries                  number
0   2000-05-01 10:00:00+00:00   0.9
```